# Moose class attribute that acts like Class::Data::Inheritable

Tags: perl, moose

I've got a class attribute in a Moose class, but I'd like it to work like [Class::Data::Inheritable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Data::Inheritable) in terms of a subclass overriding the parent's value. That is, the subclass inherits the parent's value until the setter is called on the subclass, at which point the values become distinct. e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{
    package Foo;
    use Moose;
    use MooseX::ClassAttribute;
    class_has Item => ( is => 'rw' );
}

{
    package Bar;
    use Moose;
    extends 'Foo';
}

Foo->Item(4);

# This prints "4, 4" as expected
#
print join( ", ", Foo->Item(), Bar->Item() ) . "\n"; 

Bar->Item(5);

# Would like this to print "4, 5", but it prints "5, 5"
#
print join( ", ", Foo->Item(), Bar->Item() ) . "\n";
```

What's the best way to get this effect, with [MooseX::ClassAttribute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::ClassAttribute) or otherwise? Seems like desirable behavior for any class w/class-data that expects to be inherited from.

Comment: FWIW Class::Data::Inheritable doesn't conflict with Moose.

Comment: Schwern: That may be true, although Moose objects have to inherit from Moose::Object so at the very least there would be multiple inheritance involved, which bothers me. Also you don't get any of the Moose attribute declaration goodness that MooseX::ClassAttribute gives you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found this page when looking for a solution. It's almost a decade after the original post but, as I have now worked out a solution, it might help the next person.

The solution was to add `MooseX::ClassAttribute` to `Bar` and a cloned version of `class_has Item ...` (note the leading `+` on `Item`).

```
    {
        package Bar;
        use Moose;
        use MooseX::ClassAttribute;
        extends 'Foo';
        class_has '+Item' => ();
    }
```

I can now change the subclass `Item` without it affecting the superclass `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for inheritance but may be roles would help you to get your problem solved in a different way.

Try it with a simple example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use feature 'say';

{
    package Bomb;
    use Moose::Role;
    sub fuse    { say "Bomb explode" }
    sub explode { say "Bomb fuse"}
}

{
    package Spouse;
    use Moose::Role;
    sub fuse    { say "Spouse explode"}
    sub explode { say "Spouse fuse"}
}

{
    package PracticalJoke;
    use Moose;
    with 'Bomb'   => { excludes => 'explode' },
         'Spouse' => { excludes => 'fuse' };
}

my $joke = PracticalJoke->new();
$joke->fuse();
$joke->explode();
```

And with the 'excludes' you can exactly control what should happen.

Have a look at [why roles are awsome](http://perlbuzz.com/2010/07/why-roles-in-perl-are-awesome.html)
and the slides from Ovid about [inheritance versus roles](http://de.slideshare.net/Ovid/inheritance-versus-roles).

Comment: You may want to summarize those links here in your answer; that way if those links ever go away you won't run the risk of it ever being removed.

Comment: Okay. I added the example from the mentioned link.